# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Tags: php, pdo

I'm french, sorry for my bad vocabulary. I have a little problem in my code, when I execute my `SQL` query I have this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ID' in 'where clause'
```

Here's the code:

```
UPDATE s_data_bans SET `name` = '$name', `text` = '$corps', `idCat` = '$cat', `on` = '$unpub' WHERE ID='$id'
```

Comment: What columns does the `s_data_bans` table have?

Comment: All of this:  protected $_ID;
 protected $_name;
 protected $_date;
 protected $_text; // Texte brut, bb code, \n pour les sauts de ligne.
 protected $_idCat;
 protected $_idAuteur;
 protected $_idTopic; // ID mybb
 protected $_on; // publié ?

whitout underscore

Comment: Those are PHP variables (object properties) not column names.  Execute the query `SHOW COLUMNS FROM s_data_bans`

Comment: Please do `show create table s_data_bans` and add it to your question.

Comment: Yes, it's properties but in the same time the name of my columns (ID, name, date, text, idCat, idAuteur, idTopic, on)

Comment: If the database says the column does not exist, then it doesn't exist. Show us your database schema.

Comment: @deceze, thanks ! You're right, it's s_data_news, not s_data_bans..

Comment: http://picardfacepalm.com Listen to your database, sometimes it knows what it's doing. ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing that you have not a such column named ID in your s_data_bans table, check this out and make sure that the letter case of your column table matches your query (if it's lower case (i.e id) put WHERE id= ... in your query).

Good luck